# Microsoft.Web name space missed in XP

Tags: windows, iis-7, iis-6, servermanager

am trying to use ServerManager class but I found that "Microsoft.Web.Administration" and "Web.Management.Server" are not found on XP OS.

Any help to download Microsoft.Web.Management dll or any other suggestions ?
am using VS2010 on XP machine.

Comment: I think if you add system.web reference you will have it

Comment: I have system.web but still cant use

Comment: Dim serverManager As ServerManager = New ServerManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These namespaces are available for IIS 7 and later.  There is no way to implement them on downlevel platforms.

In order to code against IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) or IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003) please see the following:

[IIS Programmatic Administration SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525041%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me to solve the same issue is installing 
"Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 2.0 SP3 for Microsoft .NET Redistributable Runtime MSI"

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=772

Hopefully this will help someone else ...